# Break an input string into individual words

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

Problem:

- Declare a variable named myArray and assign it to an empty array.
  Great! Now populate myArray with two strings.
  Put your full name in the first string, and your Skype handle in the second.
- Next, declare a function named cutName. It should expect a parameter name.
  cutName should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Douglas Crockford" should be returned as `["Douglas", "Crockford"]`
- Declare a new variable named myInfo and assign it to an empty object literal.
  Add the following three key-value pairs to myInfo:

  - Key: `fullName`
    Value: The result of calling cutName on the name string within myArray.
  - Key: `skype`
    Value: The Skype handle within myArray.
  - Key: `github`
    Value: If you have a github handle, enter it here as a string. If not, set this to null instead.

My code

```
var myArray = ['Isaiah Sias', 'isaiahsias15689'];
function cutName(name){
    var splitString = name.split(myArray[0]' ');
    return splitString;
}

var myInfo{
  fullName = cutName(myArray[0]),
  skype = myArray[1],
  github='@kakashihatake',
};
```

Once again I am not sure where I am messing up. I have been working on this problem for a few days now and find myself a little frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close, you have made a small mistake in the cutName function.

The string.split method takes only 1 parameter, the string to split by.  You've tried to pass in the array element as well. Get rid of it! (Keep in mind that the thing we are splitting, `name`, has been assigned the array element as its value during the function call)

```
var splitString = name.split(myArray[0]' ');
```

becomes

```
var splitString = name.split(' ');
```

One other issue, you'll need to change your object definition a bit.  You have a missing `=` between myInfo and the start of the object literal.  And, when setting property names and values in an object literal you need to use colon instead of equals, so your object

```
var myInfo{
fullName = cutName(myArray[0]),
skype = myArray[1],
github='@kakashihatake',
};
```

becomes

```
var myInfo = {
  fullName: cutName(myArray[0]),
  skype: myArray[1],
  github: '@kakashihatake'
};
```

Comment: I have tried using this method as well and now believe that my mistake may be somewhere else. This was the first technique that I used. I then changed it thinking that I need to select the array string to be split. Thank you for putting me back on the right track. Now, to try and solve this puzzle that I am sure is extremely simple.

Comment: The problem statement says to assign to an **empty** object literal and then **add** the keys. `var myInfo ={}; myInfo.fullName=cutName(myArray[0]); /* etc... */`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var myArray = ['Isaiah Sias', 'isaiahsias15689'],
    github = '@kakashihatake';
function toObject(){
    return {
      fullName: myArray[0].split(' '),
      skype: myArray[1],
      github: github
    }
}

console.log(toObject());
```